# How to enable Discrete Graphics Card on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ati, radeon, hybrid-graphics, gpu

I can't activate my gpu when running Ubuntu 14.04.

I've tried to follow the steps here but without any luck.
http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/enable-and-use-open-source-radeon-drivers-in-a-muxless-hybrid-graphics-intelamd-setup/

The output of `cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` always return that my discrete card is in the `DynOff` state and I can't switch between them.

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

Also, as my card is not supported by ATI so the installation of the proprietary drivers is not an option, at least as far as I'm aware.

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA      
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT] [1002:6740] (rev ff)

$ xrandr --listprovidersProviders: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x47 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

Is there any way to enable my discrete card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know how and why, but after some tries I was able to install the proprietary AMD drivers and the AMD Catalyst Control Center successfully. However, only the drivers from **fglrx-updates** worked. 
After several attempts (and reboots) I was able to configure the amd graphics (using the command **amdconfig --adapter=all --initial**) and now I can switch between the integrated and discrete video cards, which is quite awesome!
Finally I am able to use my AMD graphics on Ubuntu.